# JPQL - List of all items in collection member of JPA entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have this entity

```
public class A 
{
    private String id;

    private Set<String> categories;

    // getter and setter
}
```

I have this orm.xml

```
<entity class="A" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <element-collection name="categories" fetch="EAGER"/>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

I can not modify both class nor xml.

What JPA does is that it creates two tables, one for A entity, called A, and another table called A_categories.

That A_categories table has two columns, id column and "categories" column.

The question is, how do I get these all categories?

I tried to do it like this:

```
select a.categories from A a
```

but Hibernate says it is not an entity. I can not do it like "from A_categories" since it is not an entity either.

How to get list of *all* categories all A's are member of?

Comment: if you really have two tables, then categories should be a List or Set of Category object, not Strings

Comment: what JPA implementation?

Comment: try "select category from A a join a.categories category" or  "select category from A a, IN(a.categories) as category".  These return all categories, so you might want to use the Distinct key word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query all `A` entities and add all their categories to one list.

```
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();

for(A obj : (SELECT a FROM A a))
    categories.addAll(a.getCategories());
```

Comment: that could work. i have more than 100k records of A. would not that approach be a performance problem?

Comment: 100k iterations are done very fast. how big are the categorie sets of the entitys?

Answer (score 0):

query entity for A, lets call it a

just do `a.getCategories()`